# DimpleJS barchart styling columns

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I'm basically using a modified version of : http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_bar_labels .

I'd like to be able to add for each value a border on the left as high as the value (with a specific color for that border).

I'm not really sure where to start for adding that.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

More details : This is what I'd like to obtain : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2227188/Image%202.png - the border on the left is the issue. (jsfiddle.net/mkzTk/5/ this what I currently have which is pretty much what's in the example - I don't know where to start really for adding a border)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Although this question is already fairly questionable, since it's a general direction question and not a factual code-based question, it may be answerable if more detail (i.e. a picture) is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append a rectangle after drawing for each element of the series as follows:

```
mySeries.afterDraw = function (s, d) {
    var shape = d3.select(s);
    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("x", shape.attr("x"))
        .attr("y", shape.attr("y"))
        .attr("height", shape.attr("height"))
        .attr("width", "10px")
        .style("fill", shape.style("stroke"))
        .style("pointer-events", "none"); 
};
```

The example you mention already uses the afterDraw function so just add the contents above to the existing method for labelling.

It looks nice, here's an example:

http://jsbin.com/lorin/9/edit?js,output#J:L20

Comment: Bloody hell, I love how clean this is :)

Answer (score 0):

I would set up each bar + edge pair as its own group based on a certain data point, and then append two `rect` elements to that group. Differences in color can be used to give them their distinctive colors.

Your code would look something like this:

```
var monthBars = d3.selectAll('.monthBar') //These will be for each chart
 .data(allMyData, idFunction) //Assign and key your data
 .enter()
 .append('g')
 .classed('monthBar', true);
 .each(function(d){

   var taskGroups = d3.select(this).selectAll('.taskGroup')
    .data(d.dataForThisMonth, taskIdFn)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('.taskGroup', true);
    .attr('transform', ...) //Define the x and y positioning for the group

   taskGroups.append('rect')
    //Make this the 'body' rect with the text in it

   taskGroups.append('rect')
    //Make this the edge rect
 })
```